# Fixed td height CSS

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table displaying some data and I need the table cell  to have a fixed height.

I try with css `.tdheight { height: 40px;}` but not working. (on firefox works, on chrome not working)

```
____________________________
|        |__________________|
|        |                  |
|        |                  |
|        |                  |
|        |__________________|
|        | here's problem   |
|________|__________________|
```

see on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu4Aq/1/).

How to fix this so that it works in all browsers?

Comment: In my firefox it works...?

Comment: yes on firefox it works but my chrome not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your message (the "lorem ipsum" cell) in a container and give it a minimum height. This will save the actual height of the last row's cell.

See http://jsfiddle.net/zu4Aq/2/

---

You are using `rowspan="3"` in your first row's cell forcing the table body to have at least this height.

Change your tdheight class to

```
.tdheight {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

This will stick the last row's cell to the bottom regardless of the table's height.

Comment: why using `vertical-align` ? I need the height of td not align.

Comment: Okay, I just found the problem. Firefox is sharing the total height of the table's body equally while Chrome does not, resulting in the actual correct placement of the last row's cell.